# grid.py get no rate on dataset

Tags: python, gnuplot, libsvm

I am trying to run grid.py on libsvm-3.17 using some dataset. I am using the command

```
python grid.py -log2c -5,12,1 -log2v -12,5,1 -v 5 -m 300 <dataset>
```

[Instructions](http://www.bcgsc.ca/downloads/genereg/remcbigdata/miR/TargetMiner/TargetMiner/libsvm-2.88/tools/README) over here. But the console says

```
RuntimeError: get no rate
worker local quit.
```

and it dies. Any clues what is missing?

The data set I am using is german credit dataset on UCI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with libsvm 3.17. Somehow, this error pops out even when `grid.py` is run with no additional options. However, when grid.py is called through easy.py the execution of the script is not stopped and you are able to get the best parameters for whatever kernel you want to use.

In easy.py, change

```
cmd = '{0} -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, gnuplot_exe, scaled_file)
```

to

```
cmd = '{0} -log2c -5,12,1 -log2g -12,5,1 -v 5 -m 300 -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, gnuplot_exe, scaled_file)
```

and run `easy.py` instead of `grid.py`. You will directly get the prediction model with the best parameters.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I saw this error when the indices of my data were out of order.  For example, a line in my data looked like:

```
-1 1:10 4:4 2:1
```

when it needed to look like

```
-1 1:10 2:1 4:4
```

Is there some way you could have gotten a corrupted dataset?  There are quite a few ways this particular error message can occur.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to scale the data before calling grid.py. I got the same problem and it sorted out after I scaled the data. Hope this help.